# Braintree - proration upon subscription cancellation

Tags: braintree

I have a **yearly** recurring subscription set up on Braintree. I am trying to cater for a scenario where the user is able to have their subscription cancelled by an admin part way into the yearly cycle.

I am aware of the discounts feature but am unsure how I would apply it in this case or even whether its possible.

Is there a way in Braintree to prorate the amount for the rest of the cycle and credit it back to the user? I would not be doing any of this directly in Braintree but rather through the API via my application that uses Braintree for payments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact support@braintreepayments.com.</sub>

You can cancel an annual subscription mid-cycle by using the [API call to cancel a subscription](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/cancel).  Here's a Ruby example, but the Braintree developer docs show examples in all supported SDKs.

```
result = Braintree::Subscription.cancel("the_subscription_id")
```

A proration would only apply if a change is made to the subscription *price* in the middle of a billing cycle. In the event of a cancellation, Braintree won't automatically issue a partial refund; you would have to process the refund yourself. Here is the [API call for a partial refund](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/refund):

```
result = Braintree::Transaction.refund("transaction_id", "amount")
```

Also, keep in mind that a cancelled annual subscription will not renew the next year. The only way to "reactivate" the subscription is to create a new one.

Comment: Thanks this is also what I suspected was the case, that the refund would have to be processed manually.

Comment: If the user, Delete the Card which has some proration amount .This time what will happen on that proration?